# how to assign array to $model in yii

Tags: php, arrays, yii

Sorry. I was shorten my question because i was consider that, those users who work on yii can easily understand my question but now i am modifying so you can easily understand.

I want to update two different table at a time through single controller/view.

**_form.php (update form)**

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'verse-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'topic_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'topic_id', $model->topic_id); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'topic_id'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'sorah_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'sorah_id', $model->topic_id); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'sorah_id'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'verse_text'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'verse_text',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'verse_text'); ?>
    </div>

    <?php

            $trans = array();

        foreach($model->verseTranslations as $p)
                {
                $trans[$p->id] = $p->translation_text;
                }


    ?>
    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

       <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

I have an array in my _form.php file.

```
<?php

$trans = array();
foreach($model->verseTranslations as $p)
{
  $trans[$p->id] = $p->translation_text;
}

?>
```

if i write `print_r($trans);` Its output like this.

```
Array ( [3] => In the name of ALLAH, most Gracious, most Compassionate. [4] => شروع الله کا نام لے کر جو بڑا مہربان نہایت رحم والا ہے [5] => En el nombre de Alá, el Compasivo, el Misericordioso )
```

Now I want to assign this variable i.e. `$trans` to `$model` in _form.php file of yii framework, so that i easily access it on controller and then easily submit it to the separate table.
I also want to use it in textArea.

Hope you understand my question.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What action you want to perform on this array i-e search or save?

Comment: What is your exact required functionality?

Comment: I want to save or update on controller ...

Answer (score 0):

You can not send an array from view to controller, but there is a way (No Professional Way) to send:

put it in a session in your view (_form):

```
<?php  $_SESSION["t"]=$trans;?>
```

and catch it in controller and then destroy session.

```
$trans=$_SESSION["t"];
```

**it is better to do such operations in controller itself, instead of doing it in view and pass it to controller!**

Answer (score 0):

instead of performing this task in view file , you should do it in the controller like

```
 public function actionCreate()
    {
    $model=new MODELNAME;
// your rest of code
    $trans = array();
    foreach($model->verseTranslations as $p)
    {
      $trans[$p->id] = $p->translation_text;
    }
    // and then you can send this variable to the view by rendering the view file
    $this->render('create',array('model'=>$model,'trans'=>$trans));
    }
```

Comment: The answer is same. Instead of performing it in the _form you should perform it in the controller and then you can easily pass it to the create or the update file

Answer (score 0):

Add new property on your model like this.

```
class YOUR_MODEL_WITH_TRANS extends ParentModel
{
    public $trans;
    ---
}
```

Go to your view file and assign it easily like this.

```
$model->trans=$trans;
```